# Website cuts off connection when trying to access it using WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, webclient

I have a website on a local network that I am trying to write a little client for.

I am trying to use WebClient for this purpose, however, it seems that the website somehow detects it and does not allow to continue cutting the connection, which results in WebException.

To counter this, I have tried adding headers like:

```
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "deflate, sdch, br");
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
        wc.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
```

However, the website still cut of the connection and I managed to notice that not all headers were sent, then, I have tried to override WebRequest:

```
    public class MyWebClient : WebClient
    {
        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
            var castRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;

            if (castRequest != null)
            {
                castRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                castRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
                castRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
                castRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "deflate, sdch, br");
                castRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
                castRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            }

            return request;
        }
    }
```

This managed to send all the headers, however, I still could not access the website.

I can access the website just fine using any browser like Firefox or Chrome from which I copied the headers or even WebBrowser control, I can also access other websites using WebClient without any issue.

Is there anything specific why I cannot access such website using WebClient?

Is there anything else to make WebClient request look more like browser for a website?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that I was looking in the wrong direction.

It seems the website in question does not support default SecurityProtocol, therefore I had to enable TLS12:

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

For some reason it has caused the same issue with another local website I was parsing, which I have solved by enabling all TLS versions:

```
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```